# Is there a program that bans me from using a program for a certain amount of time?

Tags: games, process

So school just restarted and i'm crazy addicted to league of Legend. Is there anyway I can block myself from running it for like 1-2 days. I'm looking for a program. I believe there is one like this for macs, but ain't sure.

Comment: I was asking if there was a program that blocks the use of a certain programs from being used for a period of time. how is this ambigious.......... Macs have a similar programs......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is that game online? `sudo apt-get purge firefox-or-whatever-your-browser-is`.

Just kidding. I will tell you as a recovering video-game addict that the only thing that made me stop playing a game in the short run was to decide to stop playing that game - period. I always found a way around whatever self-imposed barrier I put in front of me if I was going to play it later. Only making up my mind to not play it at all worked.

If your eye offends you, pluck it out.