# Disable incognito in chrome or chromium

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I'm addicted to certain websites to the point where it's interfering with my life regularly and sick of it. I want to install website blockers that aren't easy to circumvent.

In Chrome, incognito mode is easily accessible with a ctrl-shift-n. That is ridiculous. Whenever I feel an urge to go on an addictive website, it doesn't matter what blockers and regulators I've got installed; three keys can get round them in a second.

Simply uninstalling chrome isn't an option either, as it's way too easy to sudo apt-get install it right back.

So yes, I want to disable incognito mode completely (and if possible making it totally impossible to get it back). I note that some guy has figured out how to do it on windows with a registry entry:
http://wmwood.net/software/incognito-gone-get-rid-of-private-browsing/

If it can be done on windows it can be done on ubuntu!

Comment: *I want to install website blockers that aren't easy to circumvent.*  reminds me of http://askubuntu.com/questions/252210/is-there-a-program-that-bans-me-from-using-a-program-for-a-certain-amount-of-tim

Comment: Answer is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/116319/how-to-disable-chromes-incognito-mode

Answer (score 1):

Form incognito main page:

> Because Google Chrome does not control how extensions handle your
>   personal data, all extensions have been disabled for incognito
>   windows. You can reenable them individually in the extensions manager.

Comment: Note that this only replaces the ctrl-shift-n with a couple of menu clicks. I would accept this answer if it showed how to lock the settings down and throw away the key

Comment: Note that it's impossible to lock down that setting. Disabling extensions by Ctrl-shift-n just gets replaced with a couple of menu clicks. If there was a way to also prevent this I'd accept your answer

Comment: @TheIronKnuckle  But i thought your problem was with incognito disabling the extensions ?